# Joomla 3.9.X: Website speed on page speed

Tags: joomla-3.x, templates, javascript, css, cache

I have a site with joomla with a good template and excellent performance. The only problem remains the same: the speed for mobile on google pagespeed.
On my site with joomla 3.9.x I have activated all the caches:
1) JCH Optimize
2) Page Cache
3) Cache in global configuration and compression in GZIP

For the moment the speed is 37/47 on mobile and 83/90 on Desktop.
Google always reports: "Delete view blocking resources", referring to the js and css files. Finally it also indicates that there is an unused js and css code.
These slowdowns mean 2.5 seconds more upload for google.

I have tried everything to improve this aspect but the problem of the js and css that slow down the speed on page speed remains.

Any suggestions on how I could do it?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I'd suggest not using Google PageSpeed, but instead the "Audit" tool build into the Web Developer Tools (uses LightHouse). Simply press "F12" to open the developer tools, then navigate to the "Audit" tab.

The problem with pre-made templates is they tend to use massive frameworks such as Bootstrap, UIKit or Foundation. They'll load the entire framework when only about 30% of it actually get used. This is the main reason why I hate template clubs. They focus purely on the visuals and pay absolutely no attention to performance. And yes, this applies to all of them.

Your template may use Joomla's LESS compiler, which will allow you to remove some of the imported LESS file that aren't being used anywhere on the website.

As for the Javascript, you can use a plugin to remove any unused files on the website that may have been accidentally called.

But to be blunt, if your scores for mobile are averaging around 37/47, then it's **NOT** a `good template and excellent performance`.

Always test the performance before using a template.

Comment: Good answer, thanks man. In this regard, would you have any suggestions for a plugin that removes all the unused code for js and css from the page?

Comment: Check @YellowWebMonkey's answer above. You can use https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/jquery-easy-profiles/. Remember that it won't automatically do this for you. You'll have to manually define which files you'd like to be removed on which pages.

Answer (score 1):

@Lodder's answer is probably the best one.  However, for those who cannot easily change their template, I recommend trying jQuery Profiles to remove unnecessary scripts and try JotCache as it can work with JCH Optimize to handle the caching better.

EDIT:
https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/jquery-easy-profiles/
Install it and use feature to load the version of jQuery you desire and remove other instances of it.  Same for Bootstrap.  You can use the Reports feature to show a popup when logged in as Super User on frontend which shows you what JS and CSS is being loaded. You can then set it to remove ones you choose.  It's really powerful as you can define those rules to specific pages using its module and assignments. So you can have it add or remove JS/CSS on pages by menu item, component type, etc.

Comment: How can i do for remove unnecessary scripts? Exist a plugin for this? Because i haven't found it.

Comment: I edited answer